# Specify storage class when uploading with active_storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

How do you configure active_storage to set the storage_class when uploading files to S3 (Scaleway in my case)?

Answer (score 0):

In config/storage.yml

```
scaleway:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:scaleway, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:scaleway, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: nl-ams
  bucket: fake-bucket
  endpoint: https://s3.nl-ams.scw.cloud
  upload:
    storage_class: ONEZONE_IA
```